# configuring hostonly network in genymotion in windows 7

Tags: android, networking, emulation, genymotion

i have recently heared about genymotion, so i have downloaded it.But so far i couldn't open that because of an error . it showing that some ip and dhcp is misconfigured.i tried googling and found many answers even here also, but i couldn't rectify that error. But am not sure wheather my ip and dhcp address are correct as am not good in networks ..
please help me for configuring the host-only network.

[image: response am getting from genymotion]

Answer (score 1):

I just can give you hit.

Open Oracle VM Virtual Box( path like C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\ )

you will find your device on the Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager

and then right click the machine image -> setting

you will find network

try to configure there